# Triggers on the Files Object

Tags: trigger, files, contentdocument, delete, contentdocumentlink

I have a trigger on the ContentDocument when all the files associated with the Parent record is deleted it should uncheck the check box field (Files_Exists__c) on Parent saying no files exists not. The trigger I wrote on ContentDocument on the delete event is not working as expected, below is the logic

```
trigger ContentDocTrigger on ContentDocument (after delete) {
    
    List<Id> contentDocId = new List<Id>();
    if(trigger.IsDelete){
        for(ContentDocument con : Trigger.old){
            contentDocId.add(con.Id);
        }
        
         Set<ID> parentIds = new Set<ID>();
 
        for(ContentDocumentLink cdl : [SELECT ContentDocumentId, LinkedEntityId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE ContentDocumentId IN : contentDocId]){
             parentIds.add( cdl.LinkedEntityId );           
        }
        
         for (List<Collaboration_Note__c> colNotes : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Id FROM ContentDocumentLinks LIMIT 1) 
                       FROM Collaboration_Note__c WHERE Id IN :parentIds]) {
        
        for (Collaboration_Note__c col : colNotes) {
            if (col.ContentDocumentLinks.size() <=0 )
            {
                col.Files_Exists__c = False;
            }
        }
        UPDATE colNotes;   
    }   
    }
}
```

I added a File to the Parent record and deleted it but still the check box is not unchecked. Is there something I am missing here

Comment: you'll probably want to do this in the `before delete` context as I'd assume the link is deleted which is why you're never pulling the related records. Have you debugged if anything is returned in your queries?

Comment: @KrisGoncalves I tried the before Delete but the issue is `col.ContentDocumentLinks.size()` is still 1, if there is 1 attachment on the parent and I am trying to delete it

Comment: you can test, but I assume in the `before delete` - the link will still be there as expected (since the file isn't deleted yet) but in the `after delete` no link will be there, since it's deleted already (so you can't pull the link to find out which related record to update). You actually want the scenario where 1 pulls as long as it matches your content + related record as you know that link is for the file being deleted in your trigger (and therefore you need to update your custom field as it will be 0 after the transaction is done).

Comment: when you query on CDL, you may need to be sure that you are including deleted CDLs as when a ContentDocument is deleted, SFDC may delete the CDLs first, or, cascade delete the CDLs